React-TS and drupal Login-cookie request
I have a Drupal website. There is a list of entries on the site. It is required to have a Drupal site and a separate React-TS site that manipulates entities on the Drupal site. The site and site requests work perfectly outside the context of the React application. However, there is a caveat. I have a code that I use to manipulate the site.

export const LoginOnDrupal = async () => {
    try {

        const session = axios.create()
        session.defaults.withCredentials = true
        session.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "Cookie"
        config_file.SetSession(session)
        const url = config_file.host_link + "/user/login";
        const response = await session.post((url),
            {
                name: 'Oleg',
                pass: '12099021qQ!!!'
            },
            {
                
                params: {
                    _format: 'json'
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
                    
                },
            }
        );

        if (response.status === 200) {
            const data = response.data;
            console.log(data);
            const csrfToken = data.csrf_token;
            config_file.SetCsrf_Token(csrfToken);

        } else {
            console.error('Error executing LOGIN request:');
            console.error("Error status code: " + String(response.status));
            console.error("Error text: " + String(response.data));
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error('An error LOGIN occurred:', error);
    }

    return null;
};


export const PostNewWorker = async (newWorker: NewWorker): Promise<void> => {
    const session = config_file.GetSession()
    if (session != null)
    {
        const url = config_file.host_link + "/jsonapi/node/rabotnik";
        const body = newWorker.DeserializeJSON();
        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
            'X-CSRF-Token':config_file.GetCsrf_Token(),
                    withCredentials: true
        };

        try {
            const response = await session.post(url, body, { headers });

            if (response.status === 201) {
                const newPost = response.data;
                console.log("New Worker Create");
                console.log(newPost);
            } else {
                console.error('Error executing POST request:');
                console.error("Error status code: " + String(response.status));
                console.error("Error text: " + String(response.data));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('An error POST occurred:', error);
        }
    }
};

First, I log into the site using Login and get the necessary information for subsequent requests, then I use the information from Login to send a POST request to the site. The requests are strictly consistent. I use session.defaults.withCredentials = true in order to save a token with information. However, a nuance arose. After a single successful login to the site with session.defaults.withCredentials = true, I can no longer log in to the site, as Drupal issues:This route can only be accessed by anonymous users, Because it thinks I'm logged in.
And accordingly, I cannot get the X-CSRF Token for subsequent POST requests.
Initially, I tried experimenting with Logout user. However, in Drupal, this is not implemented obviously and is not easy without getting the Logout code, which, of course, is not available. I tried changing the session.defaults settings.Tell me, what am I doing wrong?
